# Multiple forms issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an object passed to an "Edit" controller. The object is a "Component" which can also have "Component Properties" added to it: Manufacturer, Size, etc. I want to be able to add those attributes on the same page as the object's Edit view.

I have 2 forms. The first one functions correctly to edit the model.

The second one posts to the "Create" method of the ComponentPropertyValueController, but the only value that passes to the object parameter is the value entered (such as the manufacturer). The Parent object attributes needed to be associated with the added "Component Properties" are 0's and null.

What I have done is tried to instantiate a new ComponentPropertyValue object and set the id to the parent id. I also tried setting the parent object to the current view model.

I cannot figure out how to make the new ComponentPropertyValue object passed to the Create controller belong to the parent Component when it posts.

Here is a picture of the form. The form looks fine. It has the proper drop downs and seems to function correctly.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gsYw.png)

[Picture of Entity Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjPc0.png)

The model is purposely Generic. Allowing to add an type of thing and add attributes to them.

"Component" Controller Code:

```
    //
    // GET: /Components/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        Component component = db.Components.Find(id);
        if (component == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.ComponentPropertyId = new SelectList(db.ComponentProperties, "Id", "Property");
        ViewBag.ComponentTypeId = new SelectList(db.ComponentTypes, "Id", "Type", component.ComponentTypeId);
        return View(component);
    }
```

Razor View:

```
@model removed.com.Models.Component
@using removed.com.Models
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Component</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ComponentTypeId, "ComponentType")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("ComponentTypeId", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ComponentTypeId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<h2>Add Property</h2>
@{
    ComponentPropertyValue componentPropertyValue = new ComponentPropertyValue() { Component = Model, ComponentId = Model.Id} ;
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ComponentPropertyValue", FormMethod.Post, componentPropertyValue))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>ComponentPropertyValue</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => componentPropertyValue.ComponentPropertyId, "ComponentProperty")
        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("ComponentPropertyId", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => componentPropertyValue.ComponentPropertyId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => componentPropertyValue.Value)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(x => componentPropertyValue.Value)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => componentPropertyValue.Value)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Add" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

I have also tried to add hidden inputs, and here is the html for the form:

```
<form Component="" ComponentId="" ComponentProperty="" ComponentPropertyId="0" Id="0" Value="" action="/ComponentPropertyValue/Create" method="post">    <fieldset>
    <legend>ComponentPropertyValue</legend>

        <input id="ComponentId" name="ComponentId" type="hidden" value="36" />
```

36 is the correct id for the record. but it is never passed to the controller.

If after instantiating, I set the ComponentId:

```
    @{
    ComponentPropertyValue componentPropertyValue = new ComponentPropertyValue() { ComponentId = Model.Id };
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ComponentPropertyValue", FormMethod.Post, componentPropertyValue))
```

The form is generated with the value set. Yet it still never reaches the controller.

```
<form Component="" ComponentId="36" ComponentProperty="" ComponentPropertyId="0" Id="0" Value="" action="/ComponentPropertyValue/Create" method="post">
```

My view model for the two interacting classes:

```
public partial class Component
{
    public Component()
    {
        this.ComponentPropertyValues = new HashSet<ComponentPropertyValue>();
        this.ComponentVideos = new HashSet<ComponentVideo>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ComponentTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ComponentPropertyValue> ComponentPropertyValues { get; set; }
    public virtual ComponentType ComponentType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ComponentVideo> ComponentVideos { get; set; }
}  

public partial class ComponentPropertyValue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ComponentPropertyId { get; set; }
    public int ComponentId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual ComponentProperty ComponentProperty { get; set; }
    public virtual Component Component { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the following link, it's similar to your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519123/understanding-enumerables-and-viewmodels/20521722#comment30904411_20521722

Comment: I don't know why this doesn't work. I am certain I've done similar things in MVC3. I am going to attempt to do what Lin suggested and combine it into one form with an action parameter. I could easily do adds with AJAX. But I wanted to do it the normal way first.